# Using prepared statements and full-text-search in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, prepared-statement

I'm using the SQLite C interface to write an application. Since I like security, I'm using prepared statements to query the database. In one such query, I'm selecting rows from a virtual database using the MATCH keyword for full-text-searching. Here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM Emails
WHERE ( Subject LIKE ?001 OR ?001 IS NULL )
  AND ( Author LIKE ?002 OR ?002 IS NULL )
  AND ( Body MATCH ?003 OR ?003 IS NULL )
```

This allows the user to enter any terms (Subject, Author, or Body) individually or in any combination to do a search. Any term that isn't entered, I'll bind NULL to that parameter. The problem with that statement is that you can't use the OR keyword with the MATCH keyword. I'm looking for a statement I can use with the MATCH keyword to return all rows if not searching in the Body column. Is there such a statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the SQL statement at runtime to replace MATCH with LIKE '%'. Not very elegant, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

```
SELECT * FROM emails
WHERE ...
  AND ( CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emails WHERE body MATCH ?003)
        WHEN 0 THEN 1
        ELSE body MATCH ?003
         END )
```

Comment: Do you know for sure this code works? When I bind NULL as parameter 3 it behaves as desired. When I bind an actual string I get the error "unable to use function MATCH in the requested context".